# Is there a way to install pkcs12 (p12) certificate in Ubuntu 18 or later?

Tags: ssl-certificate, ubuntu-18.04, pkcs#12, p12

I have been trying to import a p12 certificate on my ubuntu 18 for a couple of days.

```
Command: pk12util -i some_certificate.p12
```

```
Error: pk12util: function failed: SEC_ERROR_LEGACY_DATABASE: The certificate/key database is in an old, unsupported format.
```

Any help will be appreciated, Thank you.